# how can i active my account,i send email to me use django-registration

Tags: python, django, registration

```
Thank you for registering an account at example.com.
To activate your registration, please visit the following page:

http://example.com/activate/d5544f645c80f8a6c9af934c03a2ee2d7902dc1f/

This page will expire in 7 days.
```

example.com?????

i click the url,but not active my account.

why????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googling produces this: http://codespatter.com/2009/01/05/django-settings-site-domain-examplecom/

> You can change it through the Django admin interface, phpMyAdmin, or however you feel comfortable. It’s in the django_site table. When setting SITE_ID in settings.py it is the ID in this table.

So it looks like you need to go into that table and change `example.com` to `127.0.0.1:8000`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this in your local or remote environment? Of course you can't activate it because the activation URL points to example.com, which is used as an example. You need to point it to your own domain.

Comment: but,my domain is 127.0.0.1:8000,how can i activate the account.thanks